# How to rollback impdp in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g, rollback, impdp

I have the task to import oracle database (big data) with the command impdp. I have to migrate big data which take a long time. Is there a way to rollback the database when during the import job has been interrupted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The flashback feature is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

By using job_name in import commnad can start the job from where it is been interrupted.